# Kendo UI : Custom Window with List View

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-window, kendo-listview

I want to make Custom Kendo Window, and there are some controls inside, 2 Kendo List View, Kendo Button Add, Kendo Button Remove. But now i just want to show up list of my data in List view inside Kendo Window.

I have javascript like this :

```
            //get template window
            var detailsTemplate = kendo.template($("#template").html());

            //make kendo window
            $("#contractDetail").kendoWindow({
                  title: "Edit Contract List",
                  modal: true,
                  visible: false,
                  resizable: false,
                  actions: ["Close"],
                  width: 800
            });

            //get data=[{"id":"1","subPhase":"Sub1"},{"id":"2","subPhase":"Sub2"}]
            $.ajax({
                dataType : "json", async: false,
                url : "/lah/getIntermediaryParameter"}).done(function(data) {
                    groupContracts = data;
            }); 

            //click button to openModal
            $("#openModalContract").click(function () {
                 $("#contractDetail").parent().css("top", "0px"); //make it to the top left
                 $("#contractDetail").parent().css("left", "0px"); //make it to the top left
                 $("#contractDetail").data("kendoWindow").open();
                 $("#contractDetail").data("kendoWindow").content(detailsTemplate(groupContracts)); //load template
                 $("#contractDetail").data("kendoWindow").center(); //make it center
                 $("#sortable-listC").kendoListView({
                      dataSource: {
                          data: groupContracts
                      }
                      template: kendo.template($("#myTemplate").html()) //get template  <li>
                 });

                 $("#sortable-listC").kendoSortable({
                     connectWith: "#sortable-listD" //for dragdrop
                 });

                 $("#sortable-listD").kendoSortable({
                     connectWith: "#sortable-listC" //for dragdrop
                 });

            });

            //make custom button close, but its not work
            $('#contractDetail').data().kendoWindow.bind('refresh',function(e){
                var win = this;
                $("#closeButtonModal").click(function(){
                     $("#contractDetail").data("kendoWindow").close();
                })
            })
```

And this is My Template :

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="myTemplate">
        <li>#: subPhase #</li>
</script>
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="template">
    <div id="details-container" class="row" data-role="view" data-reload="true">
        <div id="contractListLeft" class="contractList col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-4">
            <ul id="sortable-listC" style="min-height: 110px; margin: 0; padding: 0;" data-role="sortable">
                //looping list data in here
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-4">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 text-center" style="align:center;">
                <button class="btn" onclick="addGroup()">Add</button>
            </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 text-center" style="align:center;">
            &nbsp;
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 text-center" style="align:center;">
            <button class="btn" onclick="removeGroup()">Remove</button>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div id="contractListRight"  class="contractList col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-4">
            <ul id="sortable-listD" style="min-height: 110px; margin: 0; padding: 0;" data-role="sortable">
                //looping list data added when button "addGroup" clicked 
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-lg-10">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1">
            <a class="k-window-action k-link" href="\\#"><span class="">Close</span></a>
        </div>
    </div>   
</script>
```

So i want to show the list of GroupContracts in Kendo Window, but always got no data. When i tried to check in console.log(), i found there are many object. How to combine Kendo Window and Kendo List View?

Answer (score 0):

[EDITED]: It was just an example, you must add all you widjets in Javascriot and html like :

Try to do something like this.

```
var myWindow = $('#contractDetail').kendoWindow({
    width: 500,
    height: 400,
// here you can do you configuration
    open: function() {

//here you can instanciate your widgets inside your window like:
 $("#sortable-listC").kendoListView({
                  dataSource: {
                      data: groupContracts
                  }
                  template: kendo.template($("#myTemplate").html()) //get template  <li>
             });

             $("#sortable-listC").kendoSortable({
                 connectWith: "#sortable-listD" //for dragdrop
             });

             $("#sortable-listD").kendoSortable({
                 connectWith: "#sortable-listC" //for dragdrop
             });
    }
});

//and then show window
myWindow.open();
```

And you template have to look like

```
 <div id="contractDetail">
        <div id="details-container" class="row" data-role="view" data-reload="true">
    <div id="contractListLeft" class="contractList col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-4">
        <ul id="sortable-listC" style="min-height: 110px; margin: 0; padding: 0;" data-role="sortable">
            //looping list data in here
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-4">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 text-center" style="align:center;">
            <button class="btn" onclick="addGroup()">Add</button>
        </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 text-center" style="align:center;">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 text-center" style="align:center;">
        <button class="btn" onclick="removeGroup()">Remove</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="contractListRight"  class="contractList col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-4">
        <ul id="sortable-listD" style="min-height: 110px; margin: 0; padding: 0;" data-role="sortable">
            //looping list data added when button "addGroup" clicked 
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-lg-10">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="col-xs-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1">
        <a class="k-window-action k-link" href="\\#"><span class="">Close</span></a>
    </div>
</div>   
</div>
```

Just an example, Hope this help

Comment: If i use this code, it can show my listview but not the entire template.
i need listview on the left and right side, and in the middle of that, there are 2 buttons. Anyways thanks for your answer @Marco

Comment: It was just an example, then you can add all  yours kendo widgets (in js and html)  , I edited the example, regarding your needs

Comment: By the way, <div id="contractDetail"> i put in html or js? Because when i put it on html, the window show blank content. If i put it on JS, jquery that load $("#contractDetail") got error.

Comment: <div id="contractDetail"> is an html tag, try to do on js somethig like $("#contractDetail") .html()